# Call Int 13h in a ISR

Tags: assembly, keyboard-hook, interrupt-handling, real-mode, isr

I have written a ISR for int 9h by assembly in Real Mode.
In this ISR, I call INT 13h, AH=0x02 for writing some data on Hard Disk. But data aren't written on Hard Disk. Also int 13h, ah=0x02 doesn't work too (Read data from Hard Disk). 
after call int 13h, Carry Flag is On, but AH and AL are zero.
When I use this code out of ISR, it's work!
Why INT13h in a ISR doesn't work, but other interrupt, for example INT10h work correctly?

Comment: I'm Writing a boot loader. My code runs before any OS.

Comment: Please post your ISR code so we can see what you are trying.

Comment: Int 9 is a hardware interrupt, you have to be careful what you do.  I don't expect int13 to be re-entrant.  This is otherwise guessing with nothing to look at.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that`int 13h`will not complete successfully without the hard drive hardware interrupt IRQ 5 -`int 0Dh`which will not occur until the PIC is acknowleged at the end of keyboard hardware interrupt IRQ 1 -`int 9h`.

> 

The happy answer is that it is much simpler to use `int 16h ah=0` to wait for a keypress.